# Asp Button Don't Fire any Event When Using Popup Overlay ( jquery plugin )

Tags: asp.net

i have a popup form like in the image .. when clicking the button to raise the event no thing change despite if i use onclientclick it work fine but when using server side event it's not working.
ps:- -when using the same button but outside the popup it's work fine .. it just don't work in the popup.

[popup form .. the button is "Publish button"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IVl6V.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Update Panel with triggers.
Please share your code both of client and server side to help you better.